# Where to put duplicate calls to firebase in angularjs app?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I need to get a set of `products` from firebase in every controller, and it would be ideal if I don't have to make an API call every single time.  What is the best way to achieve this with the angularfire library?

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray

Right now I have (in coffeescript):

```
app = angular.module 'EApp', ['ui.router', 'firebase']

app.config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->

  $stateProvider
    .state 'catalog',
      url: '/catalog'
      templateUrl: 'partials/catalog.html'
      controller: 'catalogCtrl'
    .state 'product',
      url: '/product/:id'
      templateUrl: 'partials/product.html'
      controller: 'productCtrl'

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise 'catalog'
  return

app.controller 'catalogCtrl', ($scope, $rootScope, $firebase) ->
  ref = new Firebase("https://my-url.firebaseIO.com/")
  $scope.products = $firebase(ref).$asArray()
  return

app.controller 'productCtrl', ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $firebase) ->
  ref = new Firebase("https://my-url.firebaseIO.com/")
  $scope.products = $firebase(ref).$asArray()
  return
```

Is there any way to factor out the common code in the 2 controllers and set `products` at the `$rootScope` (or similar) level such that I can do a `_.find` in `productCtrl` once the products have been returned?

Comment: Make a service, and in that service have your data variable start as null. On the first firebase call, set your data variable, and on every subsequent call check for null, if null, retrieve from firebase again, else use what is stored.

Answer (score 1):

As @tymeJV says in his comment, I'd indeed set up a service for the array:

```
app.constant('FBURL', "https://my-url.firebaseio.com/");
app.factory('products', function($firebase, FBURL) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);  
    var products = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
    return products;
}
```

And then simply inject that into your controllers instead of (or in addition to) `$firebase`:

```
app.controller 'catalogCtrl', ($scope, products) ->
    $scope.products = products
    return
```

In [my trenches app](https://github.com/puf/trenches) I've used this approach to set up this trivial service wrapping `$firebaseSimpleLogin`:

```
app.factory('$firebaseAuth', function($firebase, $firebaseSimpleLogin, FBURL) {
    var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(new Firebase(FBURL));
    return auth;
});
```

And a somewhat less trivial service that depends on the current URL/route (simplified snippet below, "full" code is on github):

```
app.factory('board', function($firebase, $firebaseAuth, FBURL, $routeParams) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FBURL+"boards/"+$routeParams.boardId);    
    var cards = $firebase(ref.child('cards')).$asArray();    
    return {
        ref: ref,
        id: $routeParams.boardId,
        cards: cards,
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response.  How would I go about finding a `product` in the array?  I'm running into the problem that the array isn't yet returned when I'm trying to `_.find` it.  Where in the above flow should I do that find?

Comment: Read up on the promises returned by AngularFire. In this case `products.$loaded().then(function(products) { _.find(...` (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-loaded). But Angular-wise I'd sooner expect that you bind the object that you're looking for to the `$scope` by its id. Note that none of this is present in your original question.

Comment: My original question was about how to do the `_.find`.  Sorry if that was unclear.  I'll try this tomorrow and if it works award you the solution.