# Not getting returned array of data from factory

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am making calls to two different firebase locations to get the data, once the data is $loaded, I am creating one object. then push this objects into one array and returning array.

But I am not getting array that is been return from factory

```
myApp.factory('MybetFactory', ['$firebase', function ($firebase) {
  var factory = {};
  factory.getUsersBetsProfile = function (userId, callback) {

    //1. first call to firebase data
    var firebaseUsersBetsProfileRef = new Firebase("https://x.firebaseio.com/profile").child(userId);
    var userBettedEvent = [];
    var userBetProfile = $firebase(firebaseUsersBetsProfileRef).$asObject();
    //2. once object is loaded call second location and load the data
    userBetProfile.$loaded().then(function () {

      angular.forEach(userBetProfile, function (eachUserBetProfile) {
        if (eachUserBetProfile !== null && eachUserBetProfile.hasOwnProperty('id')) {

          var firebaseEventsResultsRef = new Firebase("https://x.firebaseio.com/result/+id");

          var resultsForProfileBets = $firebase(firebaseEventsResultsRef).$asObject();
          //3. once the data is loaded, push it into object created above
          resultsForProfileBets.$loaded().then(function () {
            console.log('Results for profile bets loaded', resultsForProfileBets);
            eachUserBetProfile.results = resultsForProfileBets;
            //4. push same object in array
            userBettedEvent.push(eachUserBetProfile);
          });
        }
      });
    });
    //Issue: this array is not been return in scope
    return userBettedEvent;
  };

  return factory;
}]);
```

Comment: What isn't working about it? Can you reduce the code so that it's smaller, but still shows your problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have tried to simplified the question, please let me know if you like me to post more info.

Comment: Way better. Jenny's answer is correct: you cannot `return` a value from the function, because the value hasn't come back from the server yet. See my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697907/javascript-assigning-value-to-variable-from-callback-return-timing/25700838#25700838 Instead you should return the promise `userBetProfile` and bind that to the `$scope`. An example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171816/where-to-put-duplicate-calls-to-firebase-in-angularjs-app/26179545#26179545

Comment: Also, there is no need to push all the bets into an array here, simply use $asArray instead of $asObject to retrieve a synchronized list. Additionally, you should be using [$extendFactory](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-extending-factories) and the $$added method to fetch your bets, which will run each time a record is added, rather than $loaded() which is essentially a static, one-time call on the first sync of data. It would behoove you to spend a good length [in the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/) and save some energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your array isn't visible on your `return userBettedEvent` line is because of how callbacks work in JavaScript.

Callbacks, which are things that look like this,

```
doSomethingCool("stuff", function() {...});
```

usually run once the function they're passed to completes. While your browser waits for `doSomethingCool` to finish, it goes on executing the subsequent code.

In other words, if you have code like this:

```
doSomethingCool("stuff", function() {
    console.log("hello");
});
console.log("goodbye");
```

you're probably going to see this output:

```
goodbye
hello
```

To resolve your issue, you need to understand how callbacks work in JavaScript.